# Is the following relationship between the sum of the prime counting function and sum of the primes correct?

Tags: summation, solution-verification, prime-numbers

### $\underline{\text{The Formula}:-}$

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\pi(k)=(n+1)\pi(n)-\sum_{k=1}^{\pi(n)}p_k$$

Where, $\pi(n)$ is the [Prime-counting function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime-counting_function) and $p_k$ is the $k^{\text{th}}$ [Prime number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number)

### $\underline{\text{Derivation}:-}$

First I started with $\sum_{k=1}^{n}\pi(k)$. I realized that the following is true

$\begin{align}&\sum_{k=1}^{n}\pi(k)\\&=(n-p_{\pi(n)}+1)\\&+\sum_{k=1}^{\pi(n)-1}k(p_{k+1}-p_k)\end{align}$

I think I can clarify the formula just through an example,

Take $n=21$

Then, $\sum_{k=1}^{21}\pi(k)$

$=\pi(1)+\pi(2)+\pi(3)+\pi(4)+\pi(5)+\pi(6)+\pi(7)+\pi(8)+\pi(9)+\pi(10)+\pi(11)+\pi(12)+\pi(13)+\pi(14)+\pi(15)+\pi(16)+\pi(17)+\pi(18)+\pi(19)+\pi(20)+\pi(21)$

$\begin{align}&=[\pi(2)]\\&+[\pi(3)+\pi(4)]\\&+[\pi(5)+\pi(6)]\\&+[\pi(7)+\pi(8)+\pi(9)+\pi(10)]\\&+[\pi(11)+\pi(12)]\\&+[\pi(13)+\pi(14)+\pi(15)+\pi(16)]\\&+[\pi(17)+\pi(18)]\\&+[\pi(19)+\pi(20)+\pi(21)]\end{align}$

$\begin{align}&=[\pi(2)]\\&+[\pi(3)+\pi(3)]\\&+[\pi(5)+\pi(5)]\\&+[\pi(7)+\pi(7)+\pi(7)+\pi(7)]\\&+[\pi(11)+\pi(11)]\\&+[\pi(13)+\pi(13)+\pi(13)+\pi(13)]\\&+[\pi(17)+\pi(17)]\\&+[\pi(19)+\pi(19)+\pi(19)]\end{align}$

$=1(3-2)+2(5-3)+3(7-5)+4(11-7)+5(13-11)+6(17-13)+7(19-17)+8(21-19+\color{red}{1})$

$=1(p_2-p_1)+2(p_3-p_2)+3(p_4-p_3)+4(p_5-p_4)+5(p_6-p_5)+6(p_7-p_6)+7(p_8-p_7)+8(21-p_8+1)$

$=1(p_2-p_1)+2(p_3-p_2)+3(p_4-p_3)+4(p_5-p_4)+5(p_6-p_5)+6(p_7-p_6)+7(p_8-p_7)+\pi(21)(21-p_{\pi(21)}+1)$

$=\pi(21)(21-p_{\pi(21)}+1)+\sum_{k=1}^{\pi(21)-1}k(p_{k+1}-p_k)$

$$=\pi(n)(n-p_{\pi(n)}+1)+\sum_{k=1}^{\pi(n)-1}k(p_{k+1}-p_k)$$

**Now,**

$\pi(n)(n-p_{\pi(n)}+1)+\sum_{k=1}^{\pi(n)-1}k(p_{k+1}-p_k)$

$=\pi(n)(n-p_{\pi(n)}+1)+\sum_{k=1}^{\pi(n)-1}kp_{k+1}-\sum_{k=1}^{\pi(n)-1}kp_k$

$=\pi(n)(n+1-p_{\pi(n)})+\sum_{k=2}^{\pi(n)}(k-1)p_{k}-\sum_{k=1}^{\pi(n)-1}kp_k$

$=\pi(n)(n+1-p_{\pi(n)})\sum_{k=1}^{\pi(n)-1}(k-1)p_{k}+(\pi(n)-1)p_k-\sum_{k=1}^{\pi(n)-1}kp_k$

$=(n+1)\pi(n)-p_{\pi(n)}+\sum_{k=1}^{\pi(n)-1}kp_{k}-\sum_{k=1}^{\pi(n)-1}-\sum_{k=1}^{\pi(n)-1}kp_k$

$=(n+1)\pi(n)-\sum_{k=1}^{\pi(n)}p_k$

$\therefore\begin{align}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\pi(k)=(n+1)\pi(n)-\sum_{k=1}^{\pi(n)}p_k\end{align}$

### $\underline{\text{Questions}:-}$

**1)Is my formula correct?**

**2)Is my derivation correct?**

**3)Can this formula hold any importance in the study of the distribution of primes?**

Comment: Your formula follows from summation by parts: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation_by_parts

Comment: @Robert Z. Why am I so stupid?